# MEAN Stack: How to bind uploads to a mongoose model?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, file-upload, gridfs

I´m playing around with upload forms in my MEAN Application (its a project control panel). I used this tutorial for implementing a working upload: http://markdawson.tumblr.com/post/18359176420/asynchronous-file-uploading-using-express-and

With this I can upload files - they appear in my upload folder.
Now I want to achieve, that the upload is linked to the project the user made. E.g.: Jon Doe is logged in, he uploads a picture. Now I want to render his profile page. I query my project model for Jon Doe --> now I want to media files uploaded by him.

So how do I post my media, to the `projectSchema` of Jon Doe? Afterwards, whats the best way to display all the media in Angular?

**------Edit------**

I´ve been trying aroud with the extension multer, and I nearly managed to make GET and POST of uploads working. Problem is, I cant fetch any data from the database. My Console gives me a `GET /uploads/media/[object%20Object] 304`.

The target is: Writing the `project_id`, with the files to the mediaSchema. So when I´m opening a project, I get all media matching the `project_id` of this Project.  I updated my code for you:

**HTML Form**

```
<form   id="uploadForm"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="/uploads/" 
        method="post">
    <label for="project_id">Ihre Projekt ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="project_id" value="{{projects._id}}" readonly>                 
    <input type="file" name="userPhoto"/>
    <button type="submit">Hochladen</button>        
</form>
<hr>
        <img ng-src="{{media.img}}"/>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var projectId = 
app.controller('projectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myVar = false;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar
    };
    $http.get('/profile/project/').then(function (res){
        $scope.projects = res.data;
        var projectId = $scope.projects._id;
    });
    //GET Media
    $http.get('/uploads/media/'+projectId).then(function(data){
        console.log('Medien-Daten erhalten');
        $scope.media = data;
    });
});
```

**Routing:**

```
    //FILE HANDLING FOR PROJECTMEDIA
   var Media = require('./models/media.js'); 
    //GET all the media
    app.get('/uploads/', function(req, res, next){
        Media.find(function (err, media){
            if (err) return next (err);
            res.json(media);
        });
    });
    //GET one item
    app.get('/uploads/media/:projectId', function(req, res, next){
        Media.findOne(req.params , function (err, media){
            if (err) return next (err);
            res.json(media);
        });
    });
```

**mediaSchema**

```
var mongoose    = require ('mongoose');

var mediaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        img         : {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
        project_id  : String,
        updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

**projectSchema**

```
var projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        author      : String,
        name        : String,
        description : String,
        tags        : String,
        updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now },
        active      : {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions.

> how do I post my media, to the projectSchema of Jon Doe?

In Angular you want to use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service. It's very simple, an example for you would be.

HTML

```
<input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" file-model="myFile" class="input-file" type="file">
<br>
<button ng-click="postForm()" id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
```

APP

```
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

//we need to use this directive to update the scope when the input file element is changed.
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

//use a service to handle the FormData upload.
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('userPhoto', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
          //all done!
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    };
}]);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, fileUpload) {
  $scope.postForm = function(){
    console.log($scope.myFile);
    // Run our multiparty function.
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl($scope.myFile, '/upload/');
  };
});
```

> Afterwards, whats the best way to display all the media in Angular?

Assuming you have your endpoint working correctly. You can do a `$http` only this time do a get.

JS

```
// make the request
$http.get('/your/media').then(function(response){

   //add to scope
   $scope.myMedia = response.data;

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in myMedia">{{photo}}</div>
```